# How to render random books if a user tries to access books route via get

Tags: python, flask

I'm now working on a book web application using flask. I want to render the user random books in the book section. That means if the user try to access book section Via get method I just render to them random books. I have searched about this and all I found is the random method, but how can I use it

P.S: I'm using Google books API

Comment: You should provide an example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score -1):

This is hard without your code, but what you should do is:

```
@app.route("/booksection")
def get_random_books():
    all_books = get_books_from_api() # this function represents the way you get a the books from the API and returns a list. I don't know how you do that.
    random_book = random.choice(all_books) # use random.choice to get 1 random element of a list 
    return random_book
```